# Diophantine equation with application to twin primes

Tags: proof-writing, diophantine-equations, twin-primes

I don't believe one exists, but here's the question:

> What is the largest $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that it cannot be
>   represented in any of the following forms $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$...
>
> $6ab+a+b-1$
>
> $6ab-a-b-1$
>
> $6ab+a-b-1$

Either (a) find the largest $x$, (b) prove there is a largest $x$ without finding it, or (c) prove that there is no largest $x$.

Comment: I guess $a,b\in\mathbb N$, otherwise everything is too trivial. Then indeed, the twin prime conjecture implies there is no largest $x$. Not the other way around, though.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Wouldn't it be an "if and only if"? If there is no largest x, then there is no largest twin prime, then there are infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: No it wouldn't. There can be such $x$ unrelated to twin primes.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Really? I'm intrigued. I was operating under the assumption that (6x+3, 6x+5) was a twin prime for all x not able to be represented as described. Can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: 6x+3 is never a prime. You obviously meant 6x+7. Well, then a counterexample occurs as early as $x=3$.

Comment: I apparently shouldn't post or comment while sleepy. Yes, you are correct on both accounts. My post (now corrected) had the second "form" incorrect. Now 3 can be represented by the second form. My apologies. Now that it's corrected, do you see any counterexamples? If I've input mathematica code correctly, I find none for all a<1000, b<1000

Comment: Now that's another story! Your corrected post is plainly **equivalent to** the twin prime conjecture, and anyone searching for a counterexample will do so in vain, be it until 1000 or until 1000000.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Is this a commonly known equivalence? If so, would you point me to where I might learn more about it? Also, being that this is more algebraic in nature, might this be used to prove the twin prime conjecture?

Comment: You might be interested in the sieve work done in the following paper related to these expressions.  The answer to one of your questions is yes, these are “well-known” expressions related to twin primes, and there was an article published about them in January, 2000.  The paper expanding on these results is found at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5KQFxR7gj3JdEFTTjEycE5JQVE/view

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Yes, and try my profile.  Read some basic number theory and brush up on Chinese Remainder Theorem.  It can be done, but most of the papers you find either dead end or lead down the wrong path entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiplying by 6 and some fiddling around, your representation of $x$ may be reformulated to state that of the following should hold:
$$\begin{cases}6x + 7 = (6a+1)(6b+1) \\
 6x + 7 = (6a-1)(6b-1) \\
 6x + 5 = (6a-1)(6b+1)\end{cases}
$$
In other words, either $6x+5$ or $6x+7$ should have a non-trivial factorization, i.e., should not be a prime.

As such, your question is equivalent to the [twin prime conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), which currently stands open.